# How to delete appengine data using Go?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm trying to delete some data from datastore using a query. Basically I want to delete all the Product entities except one with the Owner="x" . However the [Delete](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Delete) function seems to accept only a Key as argument. How am I supposed to actually delete based on a query ?

Answer (score 1):

First you will have to use a query to get all entities you want deleted. Use [keys-only query](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/queries#Go_Keys_only_queries), to minimize the cost.

Then perform [batch delete](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/entities#Go_Batch_operations), to delete multiple entities at once.

Depending on dataset size, you might need to use [push Task Queue](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/taskqueue/overview-push), which have 10min time limit.

Comment: It's the only way to do it.